# Arima with multivariate independent variables in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a dataset having dateofpurchase,locations,items,salesqty as shown below,

```
Date        Location    Item    sales_qty
02/01/2019    aaa        x        123
02/01/2019    aaa        y        323
02/01/2019    bbb        x        1023
02/01/2019    bbb        y        1203
```

I have this type of data for 2 years,25 different locations,400 different item set.I want to forecast my sales on all the locations and item level.I'm new to the time series with multivariate data.Please help me to forecast or give some ideas to me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In the `statsmodels` module, the class [`statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.html) is likely your best option.

> Vector Autoregressive Moving Average with eXogenous regressors model

Notice there's no I (differencing) component, so you will have to ensure stationarity beforehand.  (Use `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller`  and `kpss`). Also, you will need to deterime the order (p,q) of your ARMA in advance.  (Use `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf` and `pacf` to do this.)

There's also the module [`statsmodels.vector_ar`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html), which supports supports only AR (not MA) components.  You can specify the number of AR terms in the [`fit` method](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.fit), but by default it does lag selection.